How will I put a limit on my questions table but the answers table will not affect the LIMIT
Table: questions
| qid | question |
|- 1 -|--- q1 ----|
|- 2 -|--- q2 ----|
|- 3 -|--- q3 ----|
|- 4 -|--- q4 ----|
|- 5 -|--- q5 ----|
|- 6 -|--- q6 ----|
|-----------------|
Table: answers
|-------------------------------------|
| answer_id | question_id   | answer  |
|----- 1-----|----- q1------|--- a1---|
|----- 2-----|----- q1------|--- a2---|
|----- 3-----|----- q1------|--- a3---|
|----- 4-----|----- q2------|--- a4---|
|----- 5-----|----- q2------|--- a5---|
|----- 6-----|----- q2------|--- a6---|
|----- 7-----|----- q3------|--- a7---|
|----- 8-----|----- q3------|--- a8---|
|----- 9-----|----- q4------|--- a9---|
|-------------------------------------|
I'm going to put a pagination I need to limit my questions for 1 only per page.
I tried putting a LIMIT but it just give me an output of 1 question with 1 answer I have 3 answers based on question 1
SELECT question, answer 
FROM questions 
    LEFT JOIN `answers` ON answers.question_id = questions.question_id
LIMIT 1

OUTPUT:
|---------------------|
| question | answer   |
|---- q1----|-- a1--- |
|---------------------|
How will I put a limit on my questions table but the answers table will not affect the LIMIT

You get only one row because it is what you're asking for with "LIMIT 1".  You should not use LIMIT in this case.
Why are you trying to use a LIMIT ?  where question.id = x wil give you only one question and it's corresponding answers. No need for a LIMIT clause.

Does every question have exactly 3 possible answers, or was that just am arbitrary example? It wasn't clear. But if so, then simply use LIMIT 3

@FrédéricClausset I need to put a limit because I'm going to put a pagination and I need a display of 1 question per page only

What is questions.principal_id it does not exist in your table!

Thanks for editing...but you haven't mentioned if you've tried any of the suggestions here yet, and if so, what went wrong with them.

You can either try passing in the question id to the query like below
SELECT question, answer 
FROM questions 
LEFT JOIN `answers` ON answers.question_id = questions.question_id
WHERE questions.question_id = "{DESIRED_QUESTION_ID}"

The alternate way to solve it through SQL and pagination is
SELECT question, answer 
FROM `answers` where answers.question_id in ( 
    select questions.question_id from `questions` LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
)

here offset can act as your page number starting 0
